# MySQL TimeStamp query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to search for studentID within a date range. 
I only have one date in my database, therfore i only want the users to input one date, rather than having them input a start date and an end date for:
    `WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN startDate AND endDate`

So i am trying this...

```
SELECT * FROM scansTable
INNER JOIN registeredUsers ON scansTable.studentID = registeredUsers.id
INNER JOIN labSession ON scansTable.labSessionID = labSession.id
INNER JOIN staffTable ON labSession.lecturer = staffTable.id
INNER JOIN unitTable ON labSession.unit = unitTable.id
WHERE studentID = '10'
AND labSession.StartTimeStamp BETWEEN '2011 -05 -30'+00:00:00
AND '2011 -05 -30'+23:59:59;
```

But it is not returning anything when i know for sure there is a student of id 10 and that date range in the database

Am i doing the +00:00:00 wrong??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using something like `'2011 -05 -30'+00:00:00`, where you should use `'2011-05-30 00:00:00'` (and make corresponsing changes to the second condition), because `TIMESTAMP` format (I assume this field is in this format) is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Did it help? If not, give use the definition of the table plus the example row (at least both timestamp columns).

**EDIT:**

If you wanted to **concatenate**, you should have used `CONCAT()` function (see [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)). It would look like this:

```
CONCAT('2011-05-30',' 00:00:00')
```

or, more meaningfully:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ','2011-05-30','00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the spaces and plus symbols:

`BETWEEN '2011-05-30 00:00:00' AND '2011-05-30 23:59:59'`

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't changed the default date format, remove the `+` signs and the extra spaces.

```
labSession.StartTimeStamp BETWEEN '2011-05-30 00:00:00' AND '2011-05-30 23:59:59';
```

Also, I don't know if it's a byproduct of the copy/paste, but MySQL won't even run the query as-is.  The time portion of your timestamp needs to be within the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

between might not include that lower bound as an =

i believe it does include the upper bound as =,  this might differ depending on the database.